# Regex for unknown number of variables that separated by / in express, route

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I Have many links like these:

```
router.use('/foo' , require('./foo'));
router.use('/foo/1' , require('./foo'));
router.use('/foo/2' , require('./foo'));
router.use('/foo/1/1' , require('./foo'));
router.use('/foo/2/3/4/.../n' , require('./foo'));
```

Is there any way to write a regex that match and separate them by `/` delimiter? like this:

```
//for example for /foo/2/3/4/.../n url.
var first_var = req.param[0]; // 2
var last_var = req.param[req.param.length-1]; // n
```

i already write one for match. not separate:

```
router.use('/foo/*' , require('./foo'));
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're wanting to separate them if all routes use './foo'?

Comment: I want to use them in some other logic function. its not about ./foo.

Comment: Does splitting the path string by '/' not do what you're wanting to do then?

Comment: well. i can do this with javascript. but its better for me to do in express itself.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to do this in regex, this regex will work for you. Let me know, if I've missed some case.

```
([^\/]+)
```

```js
const regex = /([^\/]+)/g;
const str = `/foo/2/3/4/5/n`;
let m;

m = str.match(regex);

for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
  if(i === 0) 
    continue;
  console.log(`Parameter ${i} = ${m[i]}`);
}
```

Comment: I wanted the regex in `router.use`. you did it in javascript. BTW as i think there is no way to do this in express. i do +1.